# OpenCV BackgroundSubtratorMOG2

Tags: opencv

I've finished an algorithm aimed to foreground extraction based on video recently, but it processes too slowly per frame. There is an algorithm based on Mixed Gaussian Model named BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 in OpenCV3.0 and I find it processes quickly as nearly 15 times as mine per frame. I just wonder is it accelerated by OpenCL on GPU ? Or it is just run on CPU? p.s. I've seen some source codes of it and noticed there are OpenCL blocks but I'm not sure since I'm fresh. I will be very appreciated if anyone could help me figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the API page [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html) You will find the line:

> The function implements a sparse iterative version of the Lucas-Kanade optical flow in pyramids. See [Bouguet00]. The function is parallelized with the TBB library.

The [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) library is a parallization library and is used to "write parallel C++ programs that take full advantage of multicore performance" - this means that it is using more than just one CPU at a time, a much quicker way of processing. This can be seen on lines like this [(Line 566)](https://fossies.org/dox/opencv-2.4.11/bgfg__gaussmix2_8cpp_source.html):

```
 parallel_for_(Range(0, image.rows),
  MOG2Invoker(image, fgmask,
  (GMM*)bgmodel.data,
  (float*)(bgmodel.data + sizeof(GMM)*nmixtures*image.rows*image.cols),
  bgmodelUsedModes.data, nmixtures, (float)learningRate,
  (float)varThreshold,
  backgroundRatio, varThresholdGen,
  fVarInit, fVarMin, fVarMax, float(-learningRate*fCT), fTau,
  bShadowDetection, nShadowDetection));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! fossies is also great!